CoreSimulator storage space
My /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator folder is 27 GB with /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Images taking up 15 GB and /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles taking up 12 GB. Can I clear anything in these folders without breaking anything?
Keep in mind this is a different folder than ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator which is only 3 GB.

Attn downvoter: SO allows questions about tools used by developers. Xcode is a tool used by developers.

Run Xcode and go to the Settings screen then the Components tab. Look under the "Other Installed Platforms" section. It is those platforms that are taking up space in /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator.
If there are any entries under "Other Installed Platforms" that you no longer need, click on the entry and then click on the - icon or right-click on the entry and select Remove from the context menu.
Removing unneeded platforms from the Components tab in Xcode is safer than trying to delete files directly from the /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator folder.
